# can not retrieve the array value

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I want to collect the elements of my address table in table format but impossible. this is what I get in my console

```
{…}
​
"-LsMm5EeM0DavWwNweBc": Object { adresse: "njkbj", commune: "Marcory", nom: "jjbjkb,", … }
​
"-LsMmBCOHZzkVL_LUwiQ": Object { adresse: "bjb", commune: "Marcory", nom: "bjhbhjh", … }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

page for service

```
 adresses: Adresse [] = [];
  adresseSubject = new Subject<Adresse[]>();

  constructor() { }

  emitAdresse(){
    this.adresseSubject.next(this.adresses);
  }


  getAdresse(){
    firebase.database().ref('adresse/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid )
      .on('value', (data)=>{
        this.adresses = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
        console.log();
        this.emitAdresse();
      });
  }
```

page for Page ts

```
adresses : Adresse[];
  adresseSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private adresseService: AdresseService,  private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.adresseSubscription = this.adresseService.adresseSubject.subscribe(
      (adresses: Adresse[]) => {
        this.adresses = adresses;
      }
    );
    this.adresseService.getAdresse();
    this.adresseService.emitAdresse();
  }
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting is an object, not an array. So you have the option to use `keyvalue` pipe like in other answer (with a small correction), or actually create an array from the response.

Here's using `keyvalue`:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
    {{ item.value.adresse }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or then you create an array from the response:

```ts
adressArray = [];

getAdresse(){
  firebase.database().ref('adresse/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid )
    .on('value', (data) => {
       for (let key in data.val()) {
         this.adressArray.push({key, ...data.val()[key]})
       }
    });
}
```

With that you get an array of objects, where each object would look like:

```ts
{"key":"-LsMm5EeM0DavWwNweBc","adresse":"njkbj","commune":"Marcory","nom":"jjbjkb"}
```

Which you can then iterate like:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of adressArray">
    {{item.adresse}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

> Here's a STACKBLITZ with both options: **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-opsn38?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

In your Page Component `adresses` is going to be an `Object` and not an `Array`. So in order to make this work, you can use the [**`keyvalue`**](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe with an [**`*ngFor`**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Here, give this a try:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of adresses | keyvalue">
    {{ item.adresse }}
  </li>
</ul>
```